# Continuity of a function question?Short?

Tags: limits

I have to prove that the function $\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $x^2+y^2\neq 0$ and $0$ for $x^2+y^2=0$ is continuous according to $x$ and $y$ apart from each other, but it is not continuous at the point $0$ $(0;0)$...can you explain me what does this mean? That would be helpful....thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$x=y\Longrightarrow \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{2x^2}{2x^2}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1\neq 0$$

$$y=0\Longrightarrow \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{0}{x^2}\xrightarrow [x\to 0]{}0$$

The first line already proves the function cannot be continuous at $\,(0,0)\,$ (why?) , the 2nd one proves we cannot remove the discontinuity (why?)

Answer (score 0):

For $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, you have the ratio of two continuous functions with the denominator never $0$ and so you have a continuous function.

For $(x,y) = (0,0)$, the limit  $$\displaystyle\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}f(x(t), y(t))$$ should exist and be $f(0,0)$ for any continuous curve $(x(t), y(t))$ with $(x(0), y(0)) = (0,0)$.

Choosing the curve $(x(t), y(t)) = (t, t)$, we have $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} f(x(t), y(t)) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{2 t^2}{2 t^2} = 1  \neq f(0,0)$$